# How do I specify a proxy server when using the sForceService object?

Tags: soap-api

I'm creating a c# project which is using the SOAP API to connect to Salesforce. My network administrator has a proxy server setup. I need to configure the Sforceservice object with the server and proxy information so that it can connect to Salesforce through the proxy server. Here's what I have so far:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(userId);
config.setPassword(passwd);
config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
config.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
// Set the username and password if your proxy must be authenticated
config.setProxyUsername(proxyUsername);
config.setProxyPassword(proxyPassword);
try {
   EnterpriseConnection connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config);
   // etc.
} catch (ConnectionException ce) {
  ce.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet from my project which uses a proxy server to connect to Salesforce:

```
 if (AppSettings.proxyHost != "" && AppSettings.proxyPort > 0)
 {
                System.Net.WebProxy wp = new System.Net.WebProxy(AppSettings.proxyHost, AppSettings.proxyPort);
                wp.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;

                if (AppSettings.proxyUsername != "" && AppSettings.proxyPassword != "")
                {
                    if(AppSettings.proxyDomain != "")
                        wp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AppSettings.proxyUsername, AppSettings.proxyPassword, AppSettings.proxyDomain);
                    else
                        wp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AppSettings.proxyUsername, AppSettings.proxyPassword);
                }

                SfdcBinding.Proxy = wp;
 }
```